# Remote Desktop Services User Profile

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop, roaming-profile

I have the problem, that when I give a User in AD a Remote Desktop Services Profile Path (\Server01\RDP-Profile%username%) no folder will be createt for that user. When I check the server, to where the connection from the client goes, theres always just a local folder.

Now I'm not sure if I don't understand the Profile Path (What it does exaclty) or if theres a permission issue on the share, where the profiles should be created.

-> Gave the user a path, like the roaming profile path -> Expected a folder for the user in the RDP-Profiles --> No profile folder on the share, only a local one

-> Checked the permission on the share -> As far as I can see the permissions are set correctly (same as for the normal roaming profiles which works)